# Show that : $2, 5, 13, 17, 29, 421, 401, 53, 281,...,\rightarrow \infty$? $a_{n+1}=\operatorname{ GPF}(qa_n+p)$

Tags: number-theory, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I denote by $\operatorname{ GPF}(n)$ the greatest prime factor of $n$, eg. $\operatorname{ GPF}(17)=17$, $\operatorname{ GPF}(18)=3$.

Is there a way to prove that the sequence $a_{n+1}=\operatorname{ GPF}(qa_n+p)$, eventually enter a cycle for all initial values of positive integers $q,a_0,p>1$?

Which my simulations seem to indicate - although the sequence $a_{n+1}=\operatorname{ GPF}(a_n^2+1)$ with $a_0=2$ appears to run off into infinity.

Comment: For $q=1$, you can do this because at least one of $a_n$, $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+2}$ is divisible by $3$ when $p\neq 3$.  This means that the sequence will be cut by at least a factor of $\frac{1}{3}$ on at least every $3$ elements, so that it is bounded.  Hence it cycles.  Likely a proof of your statement will be based on this form of growth argument.  Also, from this we have a good heuristic for why $a_n^2+1$ might not work; it grows too quickly, and there are not enough numbers $n$ with $P(n)\leq \sqrt{n}$ (only about 30%)

Comment: What are the values of $p$ and $q$ you used to generate the question title?

Comment: @EricNaslund: if each $qa_n+p$ were prime, then $a_{n+3}$ is more than $q^3$ times as large as $a_n$, so a single factor of $1/3$ won't force the sequence to be bounded. Anyway, getting that factor of 3 depends on the constants: if $q=2$ and $p=5$ and $a_0\equiv 1\pmod 3$, then $qa_0+p$ remains $1\pmod 3$, and in principal we could never get a multiple of 3.

Comment: @Greg, I think the title sequence is the one with $a_n^2+1$.

Comment: @GregMartin: I wasn't necessarily thinking of using $3$, but just some kind of growth condition.  For that sequence to go to infinity, we have have a sequence of integers satisfying $P(n)>\frac{n-p}{q}$ infinitely often, and not far from this inequality "most" of the time.  There are not _too_ many integers which satisfy this, (the asymptotic density is $\frac{\log q}{\log x}$) so maybe there is a way to take advantage of how $n$ is defined to get a contradiction.  Nothing I tried seemed to work, and after thinking about it more, I doubt this approach will work...

Comment: Also posted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88282/the-sequence-a-n1-the-greatest-prime-factor-of-xa-ny/88304#88304 where a reference has been given to an affirmative answer to the first question in the case $q=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question has been [answered on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88282/the-sequence-a-n1-the-greatest-prime-factor-of-xa-ny/88304#88304) by [Gerry Myerson](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3684/gerry-myerson), I'm going to post a quote of the answer here for sake of removing this post from the *Unanswered Questions* queue.

> There is a paper on this problem, Mihai Caragiu, *Recurrences based on the greatest prime factor function*, JP J. Algebra Number Theory Appl. 19 (2010), no. 2, 155–163, MR2796479 (2012a:11010). The summary begins,
>
> > We introduce and discuss a generalized ultimate periodicity conjecture for prime sequences $\lbrace q_n\rbrace_{n\ge0}$ in which every term $q_n$ is recursively defined as the maximum element of the finite set $\lbrace P(A_jq_{n-1}+B_j)\mid j=1,\dots,k\rbrace$, where $P(x)$ represents the greatest prime factor of $x$, while $A_j$ and $B_j$ are fixed positive integers for $1\le j\le k$.
>
> I haven't seen the paper, just the summary in Math Reviews.

Comment: Maybe you should make this community wiki as it is esentially another answer verbatim?

Comment: @LaplacianFourier, ... isn't it community wiki already?